# workflow condition issue

Tags: workflow, email-alert, workflowrule

I have a requirement where an email alert is sent to specific users if the following conditions are satisfied.
When a case is created with below criteria:

```
Case market = Canada AND Status = Open AND
1)  Injury > 0 OR Death > 0(these are fields on related object liability)
OR 
2)  Injury = 0, Death = 0 AND liability record associated with case has below information
•   was there fire: Answer Yes OR
•   was it in accident: Answer Yes
OR 
3)  Anomaly reported by customer = Fire OR faulty design OR manual error
(Even if there is no liability associated with the case)
```

I have created a workflow, but it is not quite working as expected since it is only firing for the 3rd OR and not for the 1st and 2nd OR:

```
AND((ISPICKVAL(Status ,'Open')),(ISPICKVAL(CC_Market__c,'Canada')), 
OR(OR((liability__r.fatality__c >0), (liability__r.injury__c >0)), 
(((CC_TREAD__r.fatality__c =0)&&(liability__r.fatality__c =0))&&((ISPICKVAL( liability__r.CC_Combustion__c ,'Yes')||(ISPICKVAL( liability__r.CC_Accident__c , 'Yes'))))), 
((ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'Faulty design'))||(ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'Fire'))||(ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'manual error')))))
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is incredibly difficult to read because you're using parentheses you don't need all over the place, as well as mixing `&&` style with `AND()`/`OR()` style logic. There is no need to wrap every function and comparison in a new set of parentheses.

Additionally, you don't need to nest unmixed ORs and ANDs. A OR B OR (C OR D OR E) is the same as A OR B OR C OR D OR E. A AND B AND (C AND D) is the same as A AND B AND C AND D.

You'll find the logical flow easier to follow if you strip that down and use formatting to follow the decision tree. I *think* this is what your formula reduces down to, if you strip away all the logical duplication, although the original is so complex it's possible I missed something.

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Open'),
    ISPICKVAL(CC_Market__c, 'Canada'), 
    OR(
       liability__r.fatality__c > 0, 
       liability__r.injury__c > 0, 
       AND(CC_TREAD__r.fatality__c = 0,
           liability__r.fatality__c = 0,
           OR(ISPICKVAL(liability__r.CC_Combustion__c ,'Yes'),
              ISPICKVAL(liability__r.CC_Accident__c , 'Yes'))
          ), 
        ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'Faulty design'),
        ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'Fire'),
        ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'manual error')
      )
    )
```

This looks to me, after rewriting and formatting all the logic, like it will hit your objectives. You should see also sfdcfox's comment on a misplaced parenthesis (which I think I silently deleted) and possibility of reducing the logical complexity even further.

Answer (score 0):

You had a misplaced parentheses most of the way through your formula, which changed the second OR logic's behavior. I found this by indenting your formula. The error is commented here:

```
AND(
    (ISPICKVAL(Status ,'Open')),
    (ISPICKVAL(CC_Market__c,'Canada')), 
    OR(
        OR(
            (liability__r.fatality__c >0), 
            (liability__r.injury__c >0)
        ), 
        (
            (
                (CC_TREAD__r.fatality__c =0) &&
                (liability__r.fatality__c =0)
            ) &&
            (
                (ISPICKVAL(liability__r.CC_Combustion__c ,'Yes') || // Missing parentheses here
                (ISPICKVAL(liability__r.CC_Accident__c , 'Yes'))) // Extra paranthesis here
            )
        ), 
        (
            (ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'Faulty design'))||
            (ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'Fire'))||
            (ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'manual error'))
        )
    )
)
```

As mentioned in David's answer, you have way too many parentheses, and I'd avoid mixing `AND/OR` and `&&/||` like this, since it can be hard to read.

Based on my brief analysis, it seems like any of the OR values should trigger the logic, so you can greatly simplify this to just:

```
ISPICKVAL(Status ,'Open') &&
ISPICKVAL(CC_Market__c,'Canada') &&
(
    liability__r.fatality__c > 0 || 
    liability__r.injury__c > 0 ||
    ISPICKVAL(liability__r.CC_Combustion__c ,'Yes') ||
    ISPICKVAL(liability__r.CC_Accident__c , 'Yes') ||
    ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'Faulty design') ||
    ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'Fire') || 
    ISPICKVAL(AnomalyReason1__c ,'manual error')
)
```

Try working it out in your head and see if you can understand why this formula is probably what you're looking for.